# ejs, how to add dynamic attributes of html tag?

Tags: express, ejs

I use `express.js` + `ejs`, I have two cases:

1.

`<a href="<%= prevDisabledClass ? '' : ?page=<%=+page - 1%>%>">prev</a>`

But it give me an error: `Could not find matching close tag for "<%="./nundefined/nError: Could not find matching close tag for "<%=".`

I want to get

`prevDisabledClass ? <a href=''>prev</a> : <a href='?page=<%=+page - 1%>'>prev</a>`

2.

like above, but dynamic add `href` attribute to html tag `<a>`

I want to get this:

`prevDisabledClass ? <a>prev</a> : <a href='?page=<%=+page - 1%>'>prev</a>`

How can I solve these two problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one you currently have this:

```
<a href="<%= prevDisabledClass ? '' : ?page=<%=+page - 1%>%>">prev</a>
```

You can't nest `<%=`, try this instead:

```
<a href="<%= prevDisabledClass ? '' : ('?page=' + (page - 1)) %>">prev</a>
```

For the second one it'd be almost exactly the same but you'd move the condition around more of the output:

```
<a<%- prevDisabledClass ? '' : (' href="?page=' + (page - 1) + '"') %>>prev</a>
```

Here I've used `<%-` instead of `<%=` to ensure the `"` doesn't get HTML encoded.

It might be clearer to ditch the `?:` altogether:

```
<% if (prevDisabledClass) { %>
    <a>prev</a>
<% } else { %>
    <a href="?page=<%= page - 1 %>">prev</a>
<% } %>
```

There's some duplication but it's much easier to read.